# Lightning Component meta tags for Facebook

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

We currently have a VisualForce page for a record detail page in our community. I am looking at changing this to a lightning component, so far it has gone well, except for our social sharing buttons.

Is it possible to change or insert meta tags in the community page head? The record page has the "Edit Meta Tags" page but is there a way to make the tags dynamic?